# To execute bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

```
javascript:(function E()
{
    location.href="https://blrbugzilla.yodlee.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=PFM"
    setTimeout(5000,function ()
    {
        document.getElementById('component').value="IAE-Data Agent";
        document.getElementById('component').onchange();
        document.getElementById('assigned_to').value="rkumar11";
        document.getElementById('cf_bugtype').value="Bug";
        document.getElementById('cf_department').value="IAE";
        document.getElementById('cf_customer').value="Internal";
        document.getElementById('cf_workflow').value="IAE";
        document.getElementById('cf_backend_frontend').value="Preventive Fixes";
        document.getElementById('cf_environment').value="Production";
    })
})();
```

I am trying to open a page and when the page fully gets loaded I want to execute JavaScript code to auto-fill values.Therefore i have added time-out of 5 sec but it does not wait.

I also tried using the code

```
function pausecomp(millis)
{
    var date = new Date();
    var curDate = null;
    do 
    { 
      curDate = new Date(); 
    }
    while(curDate-date < millis);
  }
```

which I found.This also don't work.

Is there any method which can make the program wait till the page loads or at least wait for some predefined second before executing this line.

I want to use this code in a bookmarklet.

The program sets the field correctly because when I retry the same bookmarklet being on same page. I can see values getting set and then URL load completes.

Comment: The delay time is the second argument, not the first: `setTimeout(function () {}, 5000)`

Comment: The timeout delays the execution of function code by 5 sec?...But still it behaves same.....

Comment: The assignment to `location.href` stops the execution of the rest of the bookmarklet. The same would happen when such an assignment occurs in a page.

Comment: use of window.open(https://blrbugzilla.yodlee.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=PFM) will serve the purpose??

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout(5000,function(){})` is wrong

`setTimeout(function(){},5000)` is currect

Try this:

```
javascript:(function E(){
    location.href="https://blrbugzilla.yodlee.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=PFM"
    setTimeout(function (){
    document.getElementById('component').value="IAE-Data Agent";
    document.getElementById('component').onchange();
    document.getElementById('assigned_to').value="rkumar11";
    document.getElementById('cf_bugtype').value="Bug";
    document.getElementById('cf_department').value="IAE";
    document.getElementById('cf_customer').value="Internal";
    document.getElementById('cf_workflow').value="IAE";
    document.getElementById('cf_backend_frontend').value="Preventive Fixes";
    document.getElementById('cf_environment').value="Production";
    },5000)
    })();
```

Comment: It works to delay...but as one comment above location.href stops the execution of rest of bookmarklet. If being on same page if i use window.open it opens the page in new tab and sets the value in previous tab.Which method will load the url in same tab and will not stop the execution of bookmarklet

Comment: Once the browser goes to new URL, that's it, your Javascript is no longer executing, and there is no way for you to have any sort of callback, because the browser is no longer running your page.

So, the only available way for you is to use what you were using setTimeout().

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the `setTimeout` function signature is incorrect, as *delay* comes after the *callback*.

Secondly you can use **DOMContentLoaded** event handler to delay the code execution until page has been loaded properly.

`document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { // this code executes after page has been loaded… });`

Comment: i am trying with a simple example like javascript:(function E(){
 window.open("https://www.google.com");
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { alert("hsgxhs")})})(); atleat this should prompt an alert box.i am seeing nothing.